# Error 'Can't connect to local MYSQL Server through socket' cuando se satura el servidor

Tags: mysql, vps

Tengo un VPS en ovh con 8gb de RAM y 2 cores (no sé a cuántos GHz).

El viernes a las 00h se cayó la web con el tema del black friday (500 usuarios concurrentes).

Salía este error:

> Link to database cannot be established: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't
>   connect to local MySQL server through socket
>   '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (11)

Reiniciaba el servidor y al minuto de nuevo caído...

Ahora mismo va aguantando (50-100 usuarios concurrentes), pero en cuanto sube algo el número de usuarios, vuelve a no cargar la web y aparece ese mensaje de nuevo...

He preguntado en mi curro al administrador de sistemas y me dice que le meta más RAM. He hablado con con ovh y la solución que me dan también es contratar más RAM.

¿De verdad me hace falta más RAM? ¿Sabéis/podéis darme algunas indicaciones por donde tirar para intentar dar con el error?

Gracias!

Answer (score 0):

Si el servidor mysql, el webserver ( Apache o Nginx) y el intérprete de PHP (modphp, mod_fcgid. php-fpm) están en la misma máquina, lamentablemente todos ahí están compitiendo por recursos.

Hay medidas parche que puedes tomar (por ejemplo el uso de un caché de descriptores de archivos, un caché en memoria como varnish) el uso de OpCaché bien tuneado en PHP y el query caché de MySQL.

Como sea, si la saturación de la comunicación es con MySQL y no es que la máquina misma se quede pegada, me hace pensar que no es un tema de memoria (si realmente topara la memoria, colapsaría todo y podrías verlo en el syslog) sino al manejo de los descriptores de arhivo.

Al usar conexión por socket estás ganando un rendimiendo mejor que la conexión por TCP/IP, pero pasas por el sistema de archivos, lo cual tiene dos posibles puntos débiles: que se llene el disco o que el sistema [ya no pueda manejar más descriptores de archivos](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/36841/why-is-number-of-open-files-limited-in-linux) (esto incluye a los sockets de conexión y a las tablas abiertas en un momento dato). Si fuera lo primero, el error podría manifestarse de otras formas más que ser consistentemente reportado por MySQL, pero también podría ser que el proceso de mysql esté creando y cerrando sockets más frecuentemente que otros procesos.

Se puede limitar la cantidad de archivos que MySQL mantendrá abiertos usando los parámetros [open_files_limit](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_open_files_limit) y [table_open_cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_table_open_cache). Si el problema fuera por la cantidad de descriptores de archivo, este camino permitiría sacrificar rendimiento por simultaneidad.

---

**Dejando lo anterior de lado**

500 usuarios simultáneos no es necesariamente mucho. Yo en un foro que solía ser muy exitoso manejaba a 3000 usuarios simultáneos en la hora punta y la máquina tenía exactamente 8GB (aunque eran 4 CPUs pero nunca pasaban del 10% de carga). Y mirando cuáles eran las vías para optimizar el rendimiento del sitio (que en esas horas era mediocre) me di cuenta que no era un problema de recursos de MySQL sino que el motor del foro (VBulletin 3.6) realizaba muchas consultas muy ineficientes para desplegar un hilo de conversación. En particular, muchos de los plugins instalados tenían las peores queries.

En wordpress, la portada del sitio, pasaba algo similar. Muchas queries ineficientes y la mayor parte culpa de plugins.

Busca la manera de aislar las queries más pesadas en tu sitio. Es posible que puedas mitigar el problema creando índices que aceleren tales queries. Considera también la posibilidad de desactivar ciertos plugins cuando el sitio esté bajo mucha carga.

Finalmente, si usas [Cloudflare](https://www.cloudflare.com/) como proveedor de DNS, puedes traspasarle parte de la carga a su CDN, y tunear la configuraciónd de caché para que sea más agresiva.